# How can I create my custom Attributes on xml keyboardview?

Tags: android, xml, keyboard, attributes, android-softkeyboard

I am developing **softkeyboard** in android my question, how can i create my custom **Attributes** on xml **keyboardview**?

```
<Layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your.package.ProjectName"
    .../>
    ...
    <your.package.projectname.CustomKeyboard
        android:id="@+id/my_keyboard"
        ...
        app:alternative_key_label="F">
    </your.package.projectname.CustomKeyboard>
</Layout>
```

How do I declare an Android UI element using XML?
like above xml app:alternative_key_label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to extend the keboard view class and declare your custom attributes in 
 *res/values/*

see this:
[Custom view and attributes](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)